# Ionic 2 / jsmediatags: Getting XHR Failed Loading Head and XHR Timeout

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, xmlhttprequest, ionic2, mp3

I'm trying to search the through a directory for mp3 files and read their information so I can create a list of Tracks, but I keep getting these XHR errors:

> HEAD [music file] net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES XHR failed loading:
>   HEAD [music file]

and then eventually

> XHR failed loading: HEAD [music file] xhr Timeout after 30s. Use
>   jsmediatags.Config.setXhrTimeout to override.

[image: xhr_errors]

I have tried using `jsmediatags.Config.setXhrTimemout` (now `setXhrTimeoutInSec`) to zero which removes the timeout time but I still receive thwe same errors. Below is the code I use to read the mp3 file tags:

```
// If the entry is a mp3 file use jsMediaTags to read its tags
if (entry.name.substr(entry.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1) == 'mp3') {

        // Read the mp3 file's tags
        jsMediaTags.read(entry.toInternalURL(), {

        // On success we create a new track to the tracks list
        onSuccess: tag => {
            let tags = tag.tags;
            this.tracks.push(new Track(tags.artist, tags.title, tags.album, entry.toInternalURL()));
        },

        // When there is an error print the error to console
        onError: function (err) {
            if(err == 'xhr') console.log(':( ', err.type, err.info, err.xhr);
            else console.log(':( ', err.type, err.info);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to solve it and became busy with work.